# How to send images in real-time in Angular and .NET core SignalR?

Tags: javascript, angular, .net-core, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I developed a social media application that people can chat and send photos to each other, I did it using angular 10 as front and .net core 5 as backend and SignalR library in order to provide real-time, I could implement real-time for chat but I couldn't do that for images, after a lot search I find out that SignalR is only used for text signaling, now please I kindly request you to guide me into the correct way, what should I do in order to send images in real-time
Thanks from all who afford in order to answer my question

Comment: You can send image through base64 string. But I think there is some better solutions.